# exclude empty value from elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

i wanna get data from elastic search which not empty. when i search data on date type field it gives me an error as below.

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: empty String","index_uuid":"ZXfRDVWySt6g6sNmsKRKDg","index":"my-index"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"my-index","node":"MTIbWolDSuaH05hq9D5Phw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: empty String","index_uuid":"ZXfRDVWySt6g6sNmsKRKDg","index":"my-index","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"empty String"}}}]},"status":400}
```

my query like:

```
'query' => [
                    "bool" => [
                        "must" => [
                            "exists" => [
                                "field" => "my_field"
                            ]
                        ]
                        ,
                        "must_not" => [
                            "term" => [
                                "my_field" => [
                                    "value" => ""
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
```

Comment: what is type of your `my_field` ? is it keyword, text or number (int, long, etc)?

Comment: it is date type

Comment: I have posted answe for same. please check.

Answer (score 1):

Below query is sufficient to get all the document where `my_field` is not null as your field type is `date`. Because when you index data in Elasticsearch, it will not allow date as empty string.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "my_field"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```